# Why my push-method is not working using Ionic?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic3, push

I am working with ionic 3 and I have problems with an alert controller when I try to push an element in mi array. I do not what is wrong with my code, I think that I only need to receive the parameters and push it to complete the action but I only get a big error when I try to execute my code.

I'm so sorry, I know that my English is so bad.

**CODE**

```
  addPregunta() {
    const prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: "Login",
      message: "Enter a name for this new album you're so keen on adding",
      inputs: [
        {
          name: "title",
          placeholder: "Title"
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          handler: data => {
            console.log("Cancel clicked");
          }
        },
        {
          text: "Save",
          handler: data => {
            const preObj = {
              type: "radio",
              label: data.title
            };
            this.preguntas.push(preObj);
            this.changeData(data.title);
            this.mermaidStart();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    prompt.present();
  }
```

**ARRAY**

```
preguntas: object[];
```

**ERROR**

[image]

Comment: could you share the error

Comment: @C_Ogoo ok I edited the question

Comment: You are showing "ARRAY" `preguntas: object[];` separately, without any context. It has to be defined in a scope in which the "CODE" can see it — so where exactly is it defined?

Comment: @C_Ogoo is preguntas: any[], sorry I had a mistake but the error is the same. And it is defined into the component at the top like another variable in angular/ionic.

Comment: @ASASCED, define your variable "preguntas" as `preguntas:any[]=[]` so preguntas is an empty array. if you define `preguntas:any[]`, preguntas is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preguntas: object[];` The `preguntas` property is defined but it's not initialised with a value.

```js
console.log(this.preguntas) // will be undefined
```

The problem is in the `save` handler:

```js
{
  text: "Save",
  handler: data => {
    const preObj = {
      type: "radio",
      label: data.title
    };
    this.preguntas.push(preObj); // <-- the problem is with this line
    this.changeData(data.title);
    this.mermaidStart();
}
```

When `this.preguntas.push(preObj)` is called for the first time. `this.preguntas` is `undefined`, `array.push` will not work because `this.preguntas` is not an array.

The options you have are to initialise the `preguntas` property as an array, or check the value in the handler before your call `.push`.

**Option 1**

*Initialise the property as an array*

```
preguntas: object[] = [];
```

**Option 2**
*Check the value in the `save` handler before pushing.*

> There are countless ways to check or even use an immutable approach

```
// similar style with your existing code
if(this.preguntas) {
  this.preguntas.push(preObj);
} else {
  this.preguntas = [preObj];
}

// immutable approach
this.preguntas = [...this.preguntas, preObj]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its a simple error but yesterday I dindn't know what happend? :(

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the variable as an Array type but you did not initialize it so fails when you are trying to push into it.